# system default python can't use homebrew installed package

Tags: python, pip, package, homebrew

I have different versions of python installed on my mac. My system default python is (`$ which python`)
`"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python"`.

And if I install something with `pip` command such as `pip install numpy`, the package will be installed in the system python's site-package `"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages"`

However, I want to setup ipython & Qt working environment. So I `brew install pyqt`, `brew install PySide` And these packages are installed in my home-brew python pack-control part. My home-brew python is in `"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"`.

Now my python just can't import any `Qt` or `PySide`...
Any suggestions? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the /usr/local/bin/python instead of the system installed python.

`brew doctor` should tell you that /usr/local/bin is not early enough in your path. By putting /usr/local/bin first (or earlier than /usr/bin) in your path, your shell will find homebrew versions of executables before system versions.

If you don't want to adjust your path, you can invoke which python you want to run. `/usr/local/bin/python` instead of just `python` at the shell prompt.